# How to show all matched keyword

Tags: php, sql, join

Im new in PHP and I have create a table (bookstore) really look like this

> `no_id | author | id_book |  id_topic | quote | comments | no_page`

**id_book and id_topic** have another table eg

table for book
:

> **id_book  | book_name**

table for topic
:

> **id_topic | topic_name**

I made this sql statement for show the output in my system,but my problem is the system show only one output when submit a keyword. even though there are few similar word in the database.

```
"SELECT a.*, b.book_name 
   FROM bookstore AS a 
   LEFT JOIN book AS b  ON  a.id_book=b.id_book 
  WHERE quote LIKE '%".
```

can anyone help me how to show all match quote? i am so confuse **_**

Edit:
This is my php code.

```
$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['quote'])) {
    $colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['quote'];
}

mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT a.*, b.book_name FROM bookstore a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN book b ON a.id_book = b.id_book 
    WHERE a.quote LIKE '%'". $colname_Recordset1."%%'";

$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $config) 
    or die(mysql_error());

$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
```

Comment: Have you tried running your query directly in mysql to see how many rows are returned. Could it be that in your php code you are using `$row = fetchrow()` instead of `while($row = fetchrow())`?

Comment: You should try using double %% signs for LIKE query instead of just one.

LIKE '%$keyword%'

Comment: @phpNoOb that means I change '% to '%%' ? I have changed just like what you said, the output still show the same...

Comment: @confusingOne you really are confusingOne. So, tell me what are you trying to get, all similar names from topic_name or book_name or both?

Comment: @Sean I've try to run in mysql but when I copy that statement it seems like there have error too..  for php code, is it what you means? $colname_Recordset1."%'";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $config) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

Comment: @phpNoOb I want to view all similar word with quote. for example if i submit keyword "car" in my system, the output will display all data which have keyword "car"

Comment: you may want to consider a full text index on quote so you can use match against instead of like. of course, for a word like car you may have to either set the match against minimum to 2 or switch to like anyhow.

Comment: When you do `$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);` you only get 1 row - [`Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). You need to do a loop through all the rows - ie. `while($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)){//do something here, like print_r($row_Recordset1);}`

Comment: @KaiQing how can i set the match become min 2 or more in php?can you explain to me..

Comment: match against: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html - set min word length: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, if I understand correctly, that your query should be more like:

```
SELECT a.*, b.book_name 
  FROM bookstore a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN book b ON a.id_book = b.id_book 
  WHERE a.quote LIKE '%'
```

If you are still getting a single result (where you know there is more than one result), you need to post the PHP code you are using to extract records from the DB.

Comment: im still getting a single result :(

Comment: You will need to show your PHP code. I 'think' the error is there. Also, what happens if you run the SQL directly (at a terminal for example). Does the query return the expected results?

Comment: this is my php code. 


`$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['quote'])) {
  $colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['quote'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT a.*, b.book_name FROM bookstore a LEFT OUTER JOIN book b ON a.id_book = b.id_book WHERE a.quote LIKE '%'".
$colname_Recordset1."%%'";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $config) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);`

Comment: OK, number of issues with your PHP code. The first is a [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Next issue, you are using [depreciated](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) `mysql_` functions. You should update these to `mysqli_` or `PDO`. Another issue is the ['LIKE' statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html). You have too many '%' included. If I get time, I'll update my answer.

Comment: okay thank you so much @Tigger for your help..im really glad for everyone who respond with my question..you guys really awesome :)

Comment: until now I cant find the answer..can you help me with your answer?

Comment: @confusingOne: The answer by Wing Leong is correct (from this side of the monitor). Read the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) link. It will explain why you are only getting a single result with the code you have posted. Hint: The key is the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch the result like this, reference http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

and you should escape the user input with `mysql_escape_string`, the full php code

```
mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);

$filter = '';
if (isset($_GET['quote'])) {
    $filter = " WHERE a.quote LIKE '%" . mysql_escape_string($_GET['quote']) . "%'";
}

$result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT a.*, b.book_name FROM bookstore a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN book b ON a.id_book = b.id_book" . $filter,
    $config
) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // If you need to output table, put the code here
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: do i need to change this code to make it a loop? @Wing Leong
`if($totalRows_Recordset1<=0){
     <p class="highlight">Not In Record</p>
     }
 
 
    <?php if($totalRows_Recordset1>0){?>
    Quote : <?php echo preg_replace( "/($colname_Recordset1)/", '<span class="highlight">${1}</span>', $row_Recordset1['quote'] ); ?>
    author : <?php echo $row_Recordset1['author']; ?>
 page: <?php echo $row_Recordset1['no_page']; ?>
 book : <?php echo $row_Recordset1['book_name']; ?>
 comments : <?php echo $row_Recordset1['comments']; ?>`

Comment: I need to view all information on table bookstore (just like the question above) base on user input keyword from my system..

Comment: update of what Wing Leong? im so sorry ~ my system does not have update function..only function view is needed..

Comment: I've got some error..maybe there are error in my code to output table